# SQL How can I select the latest comment that someone has posted

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using the Postgres database (9.6) and using SQL in my queries . I have a table called **Comment_Replies** and 3 fields that I am focused on Post_ID (Integer of Post/thread commented on), Profile_ID (Integer Unique Identifier of user commenting) and (Last_Reply which is TimeStamp of the Date of a post reply). If a user commented on a post (Post_ID) I would like to retrieve the latest comment that someone has posted in that Post_Id for example

1. **Post_ID**: 150 **Profile_ID**: 10 **Last_Reply**: Jan 10,2017
2. **Post_ID**: 150 **Profile_ID**: 10 **Last_Reply**: Jan 12,2017
3. **Post_ID**: 150 **Profile_ID**: *11* **Last_Reply**: Jan 19,2017

Assuming I am user 10 or profile_ID 10 then how can I view the latest comment for Post_ID 150 ? For instance user 10 has 2 replies to the post with ID 150 but there is a newer comment created on January 19,2017 from a user with a Profile ID of 11 . For my SQL query right now I have this

```
select Distinct ON(stream_id)stream_id,last_reply,comments from
comment_replies where profile_id=10 order by stream_id desc .
```

This current query will give me record #2 created on Jan 12, 2017 . I basically have 2 requirements first get the posts where the current user has posted in (That is done with query above) and second get the last comment that corresponds with that Post_ID . Sort of like Facebook which lets you know the latest comment to a thread if you posted on it. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: What is `stream_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a `test` table

```
create table test
(
 post_id int, 
 profile_id int, 
 last_reply datetime
);
```

then I inserted the following data

```
insert into test values(150, 10, '01-01-2017');
insert into test values(150, 10, '02-01-2017');
insert into test values(150, 10, '03-01-2017');
```

then the following query return the desired result

```
select t.post_id, t.profile_id, t.last_reply
from test t
inner join(
   select profile_id, max(last_reply) as 'last_comment'
   from test
   group by profile_id
)tm on t.profile_id = tm.profile_id and t.last_reply = tm.last_comment
```

attached image shows the whole process including the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter by "streams" that the user commented on. One method uses `IN`:

```
select Distinct on (cr.stream_id) cr.stream_id, cr.last_reply, cr.comments
from comment_replies cr
where cr.stream_id in (select cr2.stream_id from comment_replies cr2 where ct2.profile_id = 10)
order by cr.stream_id desc;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what was needed